# NestJs include TypeORM repository in middleware

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have the following middleware to log all http requests:

```
@Injectable()
export class RequestMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Request) private requestsRepository: Repository<Request>,
  ) {}
  private readonly logger = new Logger('HTTP');

  use(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    response.on('finish', () => {
      const { method, originalUrl } = request;
      const { statusCode, statusMessage } = response;
      const message = `${method} ${originalUrl} ${statusCode} ${statusMessage}`;
      return this.logger.log(message);
    });
    next();
  }
}
```

My goal is to log all requests to a database. I am using TypeORM so I would like to inject the Request repository and log each request that way. When I do this I receive the following error:

> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the class RequestMiddleware

The issue is that this middleware isn't part of a module, it's just a single typescript file so how do I import the TypeORM repo module into a normal typescript file so I can use it?

Comment: Do you have `TypeormModule.forFeature([Request])` in the module's `imports` for the module where you have the `RequestMiddleware` being used?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel that seems to be the issue. Add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the module where `RequestMiddleware` is defined and used, `TypeormModule.forFeature([Request])` needs to be added to the `imports` array